# Grouping data inside foreach in blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to group a product name in may table. I found a suggestion to put a ->groupBy in my controller but when I am doing it my relation to other model is broken. what is the bets approach to achieve my what I want?

here's my code in my view blade.

```
<table class="table table-striped m-b-none" data-ride="datatables" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="">Product Code</th>
            <th width="">Product Name</th>
            <th width="">In</th>
            <th width="">Out</th>
            <th width="">Total Stocks</th>
            <th width="">Note</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach( $warehouse1stocks as $warehouse1stock )
        @php
        $totalStocks = $warehouse1stock->stock_in_qty - $warehouse1stock->stock_out_qty;
        $stockWarning = $warehouse1stock->product->wh1_limit_warning;
        @endphp
        <tr>
            <td>{{$warehouse1stock->orderItem->product_code}}</td>
            <td>{{$warehouse1stock->orderItem->product_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$warehouse1stock->stock_in_qty}}</td>
            <td>{{$warehouse1stock->stock_out_qty}}</td>
            @if($totalStocks <= $stockWarning||$totalStocks==$stockWarning) <td>{{$totalStocks}} <i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="below stock limit, {{$stockWarning}}" class="fas fa-exclamation-circle text-danger"></i></td>
                @else
                <td>{{$totalStocks}}</td>
                @endif
                <td>{{$warehouse1stock->delivery_note}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here's the screenshot of the view table

[image]

**My index function in my controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $warehouse1stocks = Warehouse1stocks::all();
    // dd($warehouse1stock->companies->comp_name);
    return view('warehouse1.index', compact('warehouse1stocks', $warehouse1stocks));
}
```

what I'm trying to achieve is to group the product code and sum its 'in'. How
can i do that? thank you so much in advance!

UPDATE

this is additional information regarding with my inquiry.

The column product name and product code from my output table is from eloquent eloquent orderItems

```
class Orderitems extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_items';

    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'order_id',
        'product_name',
        'product_code',
        'cost',
        'rate',
        'quantity',
        'total_cost',
    ];
}
```

**Progress Update**

@apokrypus, Here's the error after applying your suggestion.

**here's the updated code**

```
$warehouse1stocks = Warehouse1stocks::select(
                          'order_item_id',
                          Warehouse1stocks::raw('SUM(stock_in_qty) as stock_in_qty'),
                          Warehouse1stocks::raw('SUM(stock_out_qty) as stock_out_qty')
                    )->groupBy('order_item_id')->get();
// dd($warehouse1stocks);
return view('warehouse1.index', compact('warehouse1stocks', $warehouse1stocks));
```

**Here's the screenshot**

[image]

Comment: actually what I am trying to do is also sum the IN and OUT since they are both columns in my database. the total stocks is just an inline code.

Comment: @apokryfus I included your suggestion to my question with screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to sum both in and out then you can do:

```
public function index()
{
    $warehouse1stocks =  Warehouse1stocks::select(
                      'order_item_id',
                      \DB::raw('SUM(stock_in_qty) as stock_in_qty'),
                      \DB::raw('SUM(stock_out_qty) as stock_out_qty')
                )->groupBy('order_item_id')
                 ->get()

    // dd($warehouse1stock->companies->comp_name);
    return view('warehouse1.index', compact('warehouse1stocks', $warehouse1stocks));
}
```

This should (ideally) not require you to make any view changes.

However if your delivery note is different on each row you might consider not including it in the result since you won't be able to show it when grouping multiple rows.

Comment: thank you @apokryfos! I'll just adopt your suggestion to my code

Comment: HI @apokryfos I just realize the product code and product name is from eloquent, orderItem, {{$warehouse1stock->orderItem->product_code}} and {{$warehouse1stock->orderItem->product_name}}. I will just update my question.

Comment: I should have noticed that. At any rate you can change the group by to group by the foreign key instead. My main unclear point still remains what's to be done with the delivery note since that might mess the grouping up

Comment: I think upon grouping we can exclude the delivery note. That will only be useful i think If I lay down the history record in that instance grouping will not be necessary.

Comment: I am having this "strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given" pointing to Warehouse1stocks::raw('SUM(stock_in_qty) as stock_in_qty')

Comment: That's more likely supposed to be `Warehouse1stocks::select(\DB::raw('SUM(stock_in_qty) as stock_in_qty'))`